# ¿Cómo calcular el ancho lineal de un elemento span?

Tags: css, html5

Tengo un elemento SPAN que puede desplegarse en múltiples líneas (según el tamaño de la pantalla).

¿Existe alguna manera de calcular el ancho lineal de ese elemento (o sea el ancho que ocuparía si la pantalla fuera lo suficientemente ancha para que el elemento quepa en su totalidad?

`element.offsetWidth` me da el ancho de la caja en la que fue dibujado.

```js
['offsetWidth', 'clientWidth', 'scrollWidth'].forEach(attr=>{
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.className='rta';
  div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(
    attr+': '+span_angosto[attr]+'; '+span_ancho[attr]
  ));  
  document.body.appendChild(div);
});
```

```css
div{
  margin: 12px;
}
#div_angosto{
  width: 200px;
  height: 90px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#div_ancho{
  width: 3000px;
}

.rta > *{
  padding: 6px;
}
```

```html
<div id=div_angosto>
  <span id=span_angosto>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed tincidunt erat hendrerit, tincidunt augue vel, placerat magna. Donec convallis magna vel sem ullamcorper, et finibus purus lobortis. Integer commodo tempus sem. Aenean at congue ipsum. Cras commodo ornare turpis et dapibus. Aenean a semper orci, eget egestas mauris. Etiam dictum, mauris eu ultricies sollicitudin, sapien nisi varius tortor, quis vestibulum nisl magna sit amet massa.
  </span>
</div>
<div id=div_ancho>
  <span id=span_ancho>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed tincidunt erat hendrerit, tincidunt augue vel, placerat magna. Donec convallis magna vel sem ullamcorper, et finibus purus lobortis. Integer commodo tempus sem. Aenean at congue ipsum. Cras commodo ornare turpis et dapibus. Aenean a semper orci, eget egestas mauris. Etiam dictum, mauris eu ultricies sollicitudin, sapien nisi varius tortor, quis vestibulum nisl magna sit amet massa.
  </span>
</div>
```

En ese ejemplo hay dos div, con un span cada uno que tiene el mismo texto largo. En el primero el div tiene un ancho fijo de 200px (con scroll bar) el span dice que su ancho es 182px. Ese es el ancho de la caja, no del elemento lineal. El segundo div tiene un acho de 3000px, el span cabe en una sola línea y el ancho que obtengo es de 2868px. Eso se ve poniendo ejecutar.

Lo que quiero obtener es el ancho lineal (o sea el ancho en el caso en que fuera una sola línea). El span tiene que poder contener lo que sea (imágenes, texto y otros elementos HTML permitidos).

Comment: ¿Que es exactamente lo que contiene el `<span>`? ¿Texto plano, HTML con imagenes? ¿Podrías [edit] tu pregunta y agregar un [mcve]?

Comment: Hecho @Marcos. Agregué el ejemplo. Ojalá puedas ayudarme así.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes usar CSS para forzar que el texto en el `<span>` no se corte al llegar a los bordes de la "caja".

Aplicando al `<span>` la propiedad [`white-space`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) igual a `nowrap`

> Secuencias de espacios son preservados. Lineas son solo rotas en caracteres de saltos de linea encontrado en el origen y en elementos html `<br>`.

#### Ejemplo:

```js
let span = document.getElementById('span');
['offsetWidth', 'clientWidth', 'scrollWidth'].forEach(attr => {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerText = attr + ': ' + span[attr];
  document.body.appendChild(div);
});
```

```css
span {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span id="span">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed tincidunt erat hendrerit, tincidunt augue vel, placerat magna. Donec convallis magna vel sem ullamcorper, et finibus purus lobortis. Integer commodo tempus sem. Aenean at congue ipsum. Cras commodo ornare turpis et dapibus. Aenean a semper orci, eget egestas mauris. Etiam dictum, mauris eu ultricies sollicitudin, sapien nisi varius tortor, quis vestibulum nisl magna sit amet massa.
  </span>
</div>
```

---

Ejemplo de modificación en vivo:

```js
function calcular() {
  let span = document.getElementById('span');
  span.style.whiteSpace = 'nowrap';

  //
  let html = '';
  ['offsetWidth', 'clientWidth', 'scrollWidth'].forEach(attr => html += attr + ': ' + span[attr] + '<br>');
  resultados.innerHTML = html;

  //
  span.style.whiteSpace = '';
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span id="span">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed tincidunt erat hendrerit, tincidunt augue vel, placerat magna. Donec convallis magna vel sem ullamcorper, et finibus purus lobortis. Integer commodo tempus sem. Aenean at congue ipsum. Cras commodo ornare turpis et dapibus. Aenean a semper orci, eget egestas mauris. Etiam dictum, mauris eu ultricies sollicitudin, sapien nisi varius tortor, quis vestibulum nisl magna sit amet massa.
  </span>
</div>
<div id="resultados"></div>
<button onclick="calcular()">Calcular</button>
```

Comment: Marcos, gracias por la respuesta. Hacer que se vea en una sola línea sé hacerlo, el tema era que se siga viendo en varias y calcular cuál es su ancho lineal (dado que el span es un elemento lineal que se adapta a su contenedor). Quizás una idea puede ser clonar el elemento span y colocarlo dentro de un elemento invisible usando `white-space: nowrap` para poder medirlo. Pero tendría que estar dentro del mismo elemento contenedor para heredar márgenes, tamaños y tipos de letra, etc... Quizás haya algo más simple.

Comment: En realidad podes hacer el cambio de estilo, medirlo y volverlo a dejar como estaba.

Comment: Eso no se me había ocurrido. Por alguna razón pensé (sin comprobarlo) que para medirlo tenía que esperar a que se redibujara o algo así (o sea esperar un ciclo de refresh) y por lo tanto podía ser molesto para el usuario.

Comment: En realidad eso tampoco es tan cierto, ya que se realiza tan rápido que es prácticamente imperceptible. Actualice mi respuesta para dejarte una demo.

Comment: Extraordinario. Creo incluso que no llega a renderizarse el cambio. Parece puramente teórico

Answer (score 0):

Primero puedes obtener el texto dentro del span con `innerText`. Pero para obtener el ancho en pixeles hay dos cosas a considerar. Uno es el ancho que tiene el span ya dibujado, y esto lo puedes obtener con span1.getBoundingClientRect().width, pero para **estimar el ancho del texto, tendrías que calcularlo y esto depende de la fuente.** En el snippet de abajo hay un ejemplo que utiliza una función que estima este ancho.

```js
var span1 =  document.querySelector("span");

var textoDentroDeSpan = span1.innerText;

console.log({textoDentroDeSpan});

//Funcion para obtener el ancho de un texto segun la fuente especificada
//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2057682/determine-pixel-length-of-string-in-javascript-jquery

function getWidthOfText(txt, fontname, fontsize){
    if(getWidthOfText.c === undefined){
        getWidthOfText.c=document.createElement('canvas');
        getWidthOfText.ctx=getWidthOfText.c.getContext('2d');
    }
    getWidthOfText.ctx.font = fontsize + ' ' + fontname;
    return getWidthOfText.ctx.measureText(txt).width;
}
var textoEnPixelesParaArial12 = getWidthOfText(textoDentroDeSpan,"Arial",12);

console.log({textoEnPixelesParaArial12});
```

```html
<span>
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</span>
```

Comment: La idea es buena. En el caso general el ancho no depende solo del tipo de letra y del tamaño. También depende de márgenes, padding, imágenes que pueda haber dentro del span, etc...